# Appium - An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters

Tags: appium

I am just starting with Automatization, but I have a problem with elements.

I have this XPath

```
 "/Pane[@Name=\"Desktop 1\"][@ClassName=\"#32769\"]/Window[@AutomationId=\"win\"][@Name=\"COLOSSEO Show Manager 1.0.0.0 (64bit) .NET Framework 4.8.4250.0\"]/Custom[@ClassName=\"FooterView\"]/Custom[@ClassName=\"RadSplitButton\"]/Button[@AutomationId=\"ButtonPart\"][@Name=\"ButtonPart\"]/Text[@Name=\"STOP ACTIONS\"][@ClassName=\"Text\"]"
```

and my code is:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> SessionApplications;

        [ClassInitialize]

        public static void BeforeTest(TestContext testContext)
        {
            AppiumOptions appiumOptions = new AppiumOptions();
            appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("app", @"C:\COLOSSEO\ShowManager\Colosseo.ShowManager.exe");
            SessionApplications = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/"), appiumOptions);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            SessionApplications.FindElementByName("Stop Action").Click();
```

But the Error is still the same:

```
Test Name:  TestMethod1
Test FullName:  UnitTestProject2.UnitTest1.TestMethod1
Test Source:    C:\Users\renata.cikova\source\repos\UnitTestProject2\UnitTestProject2\UnitTest1.cs : line 25
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.1818331

Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1.FindElementByName(String name)
   at UnitTestProject2.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in C:\Users\renata.cikova\source\repos\UnitTestProject2\UnitTestProject2\UnitTest1.cs:line 27
Result Message: 
Test method UnitTestProject2.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

I don't have any idea how to find the element.
Could you help me?

Comment: Most probably people will not be able to see the error without the DOM tree you running your test against. Could you provide it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Text[@Name=\"STOP ACTIONS\"]

FindElementByName("Stop Action")
```

I think you miss an S at the end. Also I think this search might be CASE SENSTIVE.